# SQL Give me the name of all the people that I sent the same file

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that includes the userID that sent the file, the userID that the file was sent to, the filename and the date it was sent.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/855cc6

I'm trying to get a statement that returns one row per filename sent with the list of records (one per file sent) with the names of the people I sent it to at the end of the row

Something like this:

```
01/08/2014 | "main doc"  | "Jon P, Mike S, Ron W"  
04/04/2014 | "other doc" | "Jon P, Mike S"  
10/10/2014 | "last doc"  | "Ron W"
```

(where the date is the oldest instance of the DateSent datetime field).

Sorry I don't know how to create functions in sqlfiddler so let's assume that there is a scalar function named "GetName(UserID)" that returns a name of the user passed as parameter. It returns one row only.

Comment: You will need [`GROUP_CONCAT` **workaround** for SQL Server](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html). There is already [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26111335/2055998) using this trick.

Comment: Not working properly when dates are different

Comment: You need to use aggregate on date. Based on your description, `MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate values like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  DateSent, 
  FileName,
  SUBSTRING
  (
    (                 
      SELECT CONCAT(',', t1.SentToUserID) --maybe GetName(t1.SentToUserID)
      FROM FileSent t1
      WHERE t1.FileName = t2.FileName AND t1.DateSent = t2.DateSent AND t1.UserID = t2.UserID
      ORDER BY t1.FileName
      FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000
  ) [SentFiles]
FROM FileSent t2
ORDER BY DateSent
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df6dc/3) (two slightly different versions).

To get just the minimum date you can use `MIN(DateSent)` and `GROUP BY` on FileName and UserId

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MIN(DateSent) DateSent, 
    FileName,
    STUFF ((SELECT CONCAT(',', t1.SentToUserID) 
       FROM FileSent T1
       WHERE t1.FileName = t2.FileName AND t1.UserID = t2.UserID
       FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,1,'' ) [SentFiles]
FROM FileSent T2
GROUP BY FileName, UserID
```

[SQL Fiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/855cc6/3).

Comment: I just changed the GetDate() to an actual set of different dates and the result has changed... remember the right result is to have ONE record x filename with an extra field on the select statement that has the list of names of the people that have received the actual file

Comment: INSERT INTO FileSent (UserID, SentToUserID, FileName, DateSent) VALUES 
(1,2,'main doc', '2014-08-08'),(1,3,'main doc', '2014-02-02'),
(1,4,'main doc', '2014-03-03'),(1,2,'other doc', '2014-04-04'),
(1,3,'other doc', '2014-05-05'),(1,4,'last doc', '2014-06-06')

Comment: @SDDeveloper Oh, I thought the dates had significance, missed that you only wanted the oldest. I've added another solution to the answer that I think might be what you want.

Comment: Not there yet...we need ONE record x Filename with the last column a list of names (comma delimited). What can I change to make that work?

Comment: @SDDeveloper Not sure I understand your desired output, could you clarify it? Isn't it supposed to be one row per file with the recipients as a comma separated list in the last column?

Comment: My mistake..I looked at the column name as FileSent.